# Google App Engine How To Recover Lost Data?

Tags: google-app-engine, data-recovery

I created an app for a club to register members for different events, I have a datastore with around 25 entities, in the past I've created 24 Club_Event entities, each has info like : time, location, details of an event and registered member emails, etc.

Things went well for more than a year until 2 weeks ago, something strange happened and I can't find an explanation. I created the 25th event for new year's celebration. I created 2 events by mistake, because I hit a generate event button twice, so when I looked at the datastore, I saw 26 events, the last 2 had the same info, so I deleted one of them by hand, after that it has 25 events, and members started to register for the 25th event, but one day in last week, the 25th event suddenly disappeared, when people went to the link to register they only see the 24th event [ the registration link/url is always the same, the servlet just call the db and show the latest event by creation date ], so I looked at it from the Google App Engine page, it has only 24 events in datastore, the 25th event was gone, but when I clicked on "Datastore Admin", it said : "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", and under it I clicked on "Go back to the previous page." then it showed "Club_Event" with 25 "# Entities", which meant it actually had 25 events, but somehow could only list/show me 24 of them.

So I had to create the 25th event again, and entered the member emails by hand to compensate the lost info, and then the registration was available again for members to register. But the strange thing happened again on 12-31, in the morning I checked the site, it was OK, but by 3 or 4 pm the 25th event disappeared again, and when I clicked on "Datastore Admin", it said : "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", and under it I clicked on "Go back to the previous page." then it showed "Club_Event" with only 24 "# Entities". I checked my Quota Details, the app only used 1%,2% of resources, why is this happening ? Is it because I manually deleted a duplicate event 2 weeks ago ? I never deleted an event before that, it was running fine, and only went wrong after I deleted one event by hand.

The registration link is: http://asfa-web.appspot.com/Singles_Club_Event_Sign_Up

It's now still showing the 24th event.
Can someone from Google App Engine contact me to fix this problem?

@Jimmy Kane : Maybe you can delete event by Java program, but my program doesn't have the code in it to delete events, it can only create, so when I saw 2 entities for the same event, I went in from admin page and deleted it.

@Paul C : It acted as if nothing happened, no error message, instead of listing 25 events, it can only show me the first 24 events.

Comment: > I deleted one of them by hand 
Can you add the code you used to delete the entity to your question?

Comment: "I deleted it by hand" meant I got into the Google App Engine account and clicked on "Datastore Viewer", select the entity and clicked on the "delete" button on the "https://appengine.google.com/datastore/explorer?..." site.

Comment: when the error happened it likely generated an error in the logs. Is there (filter to "error")?

Comment: You can only delete event's by data-store admin ? I mean we are not talking about sec holes in your app....

Answer (score 1):

If you need to contact Google App Engine team directly there is an expensive option called Premium account, but I am pretty sure they will not help with your issue.

I guess when you said "I deleted one of them by hand" it means you used the datastore manager. When you deleted information it is not possible recover it  again.

Comment: I'm not trying to recover the one I deleted, but recover the 2nd one I never deleted, which disappeared by itself.